# Sending Envelope through the EnvelopeService (Docusign APEX Toolkit)

Tags: docusignapi, apex, docusignapextoolkit

I am trying to send the envelopes through the APEX toolkit (Docusign for Salesforce Essentials).
Following the documentation from [here](https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/code-examples/salesforce-sending-signing-template)

```
Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(myEnvelope, true);
```

When this statement is executed, i am having this error -

`common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`

Send Envelope call is doing both the callout and DML updates back to the salesforce record to attach the envelopes

From the documentation provided, there are 3 arguments for the sendEnvelope method which takes Envelope, sendNow flag and updateNow flag. So if i set the 3rd argument to false, that would separate the Callout and DML updates!!

But looks like, sendEnvelope method can only take 2 arguments!

Can anyone help me how to overcome this??

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if you had made any DML operations before calling `sendEnvelope()` within the same transaction.
Where a common pattern may be to create/update a record and then send an envelope for it, the solutions would be to call `sendEnvelope()` via a @future method or somehow separate the record DML and the callout.